# Objects of com from a type library heap or stack

Tags: c++

When we create objects from a type library for instance

```
SomeClassPtr some_obj(__uuidof(SomeImplementation));
```

is some_obj created on a heap or stack ? I mean is it like

```
SomeClassPtr *some_obj = new SomeImplementation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your "pointer" (`SomeClassPtr`) is pointing to a block of memory which will be heap allocated.

However, it's not *necessarily* performing the heap allocation, as it's actually a reference counted type which handles the allocation and deallocation (via [`IUnknown::AddRef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`IUnknown::Release`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  This means it may be acquiring and incrementing the reference count of an object which was previously allocated, depending on the type stored in the COM pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Wrong way to think about it.  Not the stack.

But that's where the guessing ends.  This COM object could live in a different process.  Or on a machine half-way around the world.  All you got is an interface pointer, what it points to you don't know.  Could be the actual object allocated on the heap.  Could be a proxy that talks to a stub located somewhere else.  Anywhere else.  That's a feature, avoid caring about it.

Comment: So are there any chances of it running out of scope of a method ?

Comment: Your *reference* can go out of scope without the *instance* of the object being deallocated, and vice versa; think in terms of the life-cycle of the reference to the object and the life-cycle of the object itself.

Comment: It's not a very meaningful question.  Stuff stops at the last curly brace of a method.  If you haven't called Release() on the interface pointer nor have it stored somewhere so you can use it later then you'll leak memory.  Somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a little wierder than that.

Strictly speaking, the first example is a stack variable, and the second example is a heap variable (assuming new hasnt been overridden.

The wierd part happens because, by the nature of COM, you don't get know what or where or if (if the result is an AddRef, there might not be, for example) any other allocation happens; in particular, for allocations that need to cross thread/process boundaries (which will always be the case for out of process servers), the default implementation of IMalloc::Alloc (CoTaskMemAlloc()) is to allocate from one of the heaps of the process in which the COM object is actually created/instantiated.

As pointed out elsewhere, that's a feature; you shouldn't need to care.